# How do I elegantly calculate a variable in an R data.frame that uses values in a previous row?

Tags: r

Here is a simple scenario I constructed:

Say I have the following:

```
set.seed(1)
id<-sample(3,10,replace = TRUE)
n<-1:10
x<-round(runif(10,30,40))
df<-data.frame(id,n,x)
df
   id  n  x
1   1  1 32
2   2  2 32
3   2  3 37
4   3  4 34
5   1  5 38
6   3  6 35
7   3  7 37
8   2  8 40
9   2  9 34
10  1 10 38
```

How do I elegantly calculate x.lag where x.lag is a previous x for the same  id or 0 if a previous value does not exist.

This is what I did but I'm not happy with it:

```
df$x.lag<-rep(0,10)
for (id in 1:3)
 df[df$id==id,]$x.lag<-c(0,df[df$id==id,]$x)[1:sum(df$id==id)]
df
   id  n  x x.lag
1   1  1 32     0
2   2  2 32     0
3   2  3 37    32
4   3  4 34     0
5   1  5 38    32
6   3  6 35    34
7   3  7 37    35
8   2  8 40    37
9   2  9 34    40
10  1 10 38    38
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, x.lag :=  shift(x, fill=0), id]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(x.lag = lag(x, default = 0))
```

---

Or using `ave` from `base R`

```
df$x.lag <- with(df, ave(x, id, FUN = function(x) c(0, x[-length(x)])))
df$x.lag
#[1]  0  0 32  0 32 34 35 37 40 38
```

Comment: yeah, you beat me by seconds :)

Comment: I am so jealous of you guys @neilfws -- how does one reach this level of Zen

Comment: I feel like a having been struck speechless by a most sharp couplet -- thanks for making my day

Comment: Keep practising! We were all beginners once. I look at my own code from just a few years ago and shudder. It helps when your job involves writing code every day.

Comment: Such an elegant solution @akrun +1